# Office 365 mail statistics

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps

I am trying to collect mail statistics across multiple users in my organization. Ideally I would like to build [a service or a daemon](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/) that uses the [Notification API's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations), to receive notification whenever a user in the organization receives a mail in his or her inbox.
However it seems from the documentation that the "notification API requests are always performed on the behalf of the current user".

How can a background service get notifications about another user's mailbox events?

Answer (score 2):

> **Target user**
>
> The Notifications API requests are always performed on
> behalf of the current user.

As the document pointed that the Outlook notification API doesn’t support the daemon service at present. You may consider to use the [Message Tracing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200668(v=exchg.150).aspx) to see whether it meets your business requirement.

And if you want the Outlook REST API to support for daemon service, you can try to submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks!, The [Mail API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) document states the same that "The Mail API requests are always performed on behalf of the current user", but a service using client credential flow can get [permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/application-manifest) to read user mailboxes. I am wondering if there is a way to get notifications as well. I will leave the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [App-Only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) to subscribe to notifications for **mailfolders/inbox/messages** on multiple mailboxes.
However, you will need a subscription per mailbox and you will need to manage all these subscriptions.